# Submit Partial View Data with main form in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

How Do I submit Data in Partial View on submit on Main View.the partial view doesn't have a separate submit button

I'm trying to Add Multiple Products to in a single Order.Each Product is Partial View.
User can add multiple Products on click of "plus sign". I want all Products to submitted when I submit the Order.
My Place Order View is

```
@model MyApp.Models.Order_Detail
       @section scriptsection {
        <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $(".addProduct").live("click", function () {
                    $.get("AddProduct",
                    function (data) {
                        $("#Products").append(data);
                        HideshowMinusButton();
                    });
                });
        </script>
    }
    @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Order</legend>

            <div class="editor-label">
                Customer
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(c=>c.Order.CustomerID,(List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Customers)
            </div>
            <div>
                <fieldset id="Products">
                    <legend>Products</legend>
                    @Html.Partial("AddProduct")
                </fieldset>
            </div>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Order.OrderDate)
            </div>
            <p>
               <input type="submit" value="Create" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>
```

On Submit Button Click How Do I get  all Products in my Order?

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PlaceOrder(Order_detail Ord) //Ord Doesn't Contain Products ??
{
//Add Order to Db
return View("Success");
```

}

Answer (score 2):

have a look at this page, i think it will be able to help you.

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/

you can change your action method to

```
public ActionResult PlaceOrder(Order_detail Ord, Products[] products)
```

or use http://www.nuget.org/packages/BeginCollectionItem/ to model bind into the Order_detail model.

Comment: it explain how to bind complex object...but the no of items are fixed....in my Question user can add multiple products...how to do that?....also you have added the second parameter(products) how to get all products in that parameter

Answer (score 0):

You can use form collection in the post method to get the data in the partial view.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PlaceOrder(Order_detail Ord, FormCollection fc)
{
  string value = fc.getValue("textBoxName");
}
```

You will get the value in form collection only if the control has name property.

Ex:

```
<input name="users" type="text"/>
```

then

```
String Value = fc.getvalue("users");
```

Comment: Thanks..that helped a lot...but if user adds multiple products there would be multiple input tags with same name....How can I get value of those?

Comment: then you should use fc.getvalues("users") and iterate over the result to get individual values of the control